# What use instead of Multiple wildcards in XCOPY

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, copy, xcopy

There is no way to use multiple wildcart in XCOPY:

```
XCOPY /D:%DATE%/s/i/y \\server\folder1\different_folders_*\*_CPU2* %DESTINATION_PATH%
```

Im was googling for some substitution for those, but my search wasnt successful.
Is there any other way to make this search?
I would be glad is you point me to some links where i can improve my skills.

Comment: No, you can't, this is simply not supported; you can however use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html): `for /D %%D in ("\\server\folder1\different_folders_*") do xcopy /D:%DATE% /S /I /Y "%%~D\*_CPU2*" "%DESTINATION_PATH%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using dates for the seach, so i can do this:

```
:while
  if %fromDate% leq %toDate% (  
  XCOPY /s/i/y \\server\folder1\different_folders_%fromDate%\*_CPU2* %DESTINATION_PATH%

::incrementing the date %fromdate%

goto :while
)
```

if somebody interested how I increment the date:
im using the format YYYYMMDD (ex 20170520)

```
SET /A "fromDate=!fromDate! + 1"
    IF %fromDate:~6,2% == 31 (
        SET /A "fromDate=!fromDate! + 69"
    )
    IF %fromDate:~4,2% == 13 (
        SET /A "fromD
    )
```